# How can i set the image inside a nine patch image custom image

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I am setting up a app and i need to set the image inside my nine patch image given below like the app in the description

> see the second screenshot of the app

I Tried setting the nine patch image in the xml file but it doesn't help much do i need to set the custom view

[instasquare link of the app i am trying to make](https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=com.ninesquaretech.instasquare&hl=en)

[lets take this image and say i want to set the image into the boxes you see in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kKfl.png)
**i want to set the image in the above image like the screenshot of the app given in the above see the second screenshot**

Comment: Better using [vector.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)

Comment: it is a nine patch image and i want to set the image inside that  black boxes that actually is highlighting

Comment: @pskink its ready i have updated the image some what idea

Comment: because we can use nine patch as a background and create a custom view and if you have any other idea you are free to share

Comment: @pskink because nine patch image is faster in some cases